# FFMPEG из видео получить wav

Tags: ffmpeg

Чтобы из видео получить wav файл, применяю команду

```
ffmpeg -i '+file+' -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 -async 48000 -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1  -acodec pcm_s16le -vn '+newdir+'/2.wav
```

Трудность в том, что видео весит 25мб, а wav файл из него, целых 60мб. Как так выходит, что аудио с видео весит меньше, чем аудиодорожка конвертированная wav.

Возможно ли это поправить?

Comment: Wave - формат несжатого звука. Сожмите в ogg/mp3/amr.

Comment: В дальнейшем необходимо обработать его через

Comment: wav = wave.open(f'{patch}2333_fixed.wav', mode="r") Для дальнейшего построения спектрограммы

Comment: но спектрограмму можно стоить не сохраняя файл на лету прямо из видео

Comment: Не подскажете пожалуйста, как строить ее на лету из видео?

Comment: Да у меня что из аудио что из видео одинакого получается: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -lavfi showspectrumpic=s=2560x400:mode=separate outfile.png`

Comment: А вот так я запустил видео вместе со спектрограммой в одном окне: `ffplay -f lavfi 'amovie=/Users/un/PM9tNJRg.mkv:s=dv+da[v][a];[a]asplit[asp][out1];[asp]showspectrum=size=1920x1080:mode=separate:slide=scroll[spect];[v]scale=1920:-1[v];[v][spect]vstack[out0]'`

Comment: https://imgur.com/pUTzgsz  - не оно?

Comment: Необходима линейная спектрограмма, точнее не сама спектрограмма, а ее массив значений по которой выстраивается. Дабы была возможность применить нормированную кроскорреляцию. То есть взять основную целиком, данные массива и найти вхождение отрезка другого массива с возможностью погрешности в 20%

Comment: Хелпс, как получить массив значений по которой собственно и выстраивается спектограмма

Comment: Ну по сути, Wave-файл - это и есть та записанная матрица, как раз те числа, которые вы хотите получить. Правда их слишком много и в спектрограмме отражаются лишь некоторые усреднённые значения, по которым уже сложно восстановить звук. Есть отличная статья на английском, которая может дать новые идеи. https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-audio-data-fourier-transform-fft-spectrogram-and-speech-recognition-a4072d228520 . Если это слишком сложно, есть очень простой вариант, разобрать саму спектрограмму обратно на числа. Это легко и не будет требовать гигабайтов памяти.

Comment: То есть, по сути, если взять звуковой файл, и, сжать до sample_rate из 16k до, например, просто 16, усреднить все значения на каждый sample, то получится искомая матрица чисел.

Comment: Аналогично с диапазонами частот. В спектрограмме каждый пиксель высоте соответствует своему диапазону частот, и что-бы чисел на каждый sample было не сотни тысяч, просто увеличивается диапазоны частот.

Comment: Я чуть позже попробую собрать для вас команду ffmpeg для сжатия звука до уровня, по которому можно построить спектрограмму. И уже после можно читать этот маленький файл, в нем будут приемлемое количество чисел для отображения в текстовом виде.

Comment: Нашел для вас очень просто рабочий код https://gitlab.com/zeograd/audio-display/-/tree/master/ Он как раз читает звуковой файл и собирает спектрограмму в картинку. Немного изменив его, можно добиться вывода результата не картинкой, а выдавать каждый пиксель спектрограммы целыми числами по 16 или 24 бит. К сожалению, прога берет на вход wav-файл, а хотелось бы чтобы брала поток из ffmpeg. До этого надо её немного подшаманить.

Comment: Еще мне случайно попалась статья https://swharden.com/blog/2016-07-19-realtime-audio-visualization-in-python/ .

Comment: Как должна работать кроскорреляция? Какую БД вы используете?

Comment: mysql, интерфейс phpmyadmin. Есть массивы(сформированные по спектрограмме, либо иначе). Они урезанные, то есть из 60 секунд, беру 20, с 20 сек по 40. Данные обрезки сохраняю к публикации. Затем, пользователь загружает контент и задача в том, чтобы система проверила. Не был ли данный контент ранее опубликован. То есть отрезок(массив) необходимо сопоставить с тем массивом(который только ко что сформирован по загруженному файлу). Из 60 сек, перебрать его те 20 сек(массив) и найти совпадение.

Comment: Будь задача найти 100% сходство, не составила труда. Просто привести массивы в строчку и найти вхождение по строке. Но необходимо допустить отклонение, скажем в 20%. То есть это возможно будет аудиодорожка в более или менее высоких тонак. Но композиция таже. Собственно задача такая.

Comment: Ранее разобрался с тем, как сравнивать шаблоны, изображения те же спектограммы сохраненные изображение. Но это более длительный процесс, нежели находит вхождение сразу  массивах, не подгружая и не накладывая шаблоны. Мне бы сперва понять, как возможно получить массив спектограммы сразу на лету. Это облегчит дальнейшую работу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115936/discussion-between-did-and--).